# Convert year string into datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a date column in my dataframe that consists of strings like this...'201512' 
I would like to convert it into a datetime object of just year to do some time series analysis.

I tried...

```
df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

and something similar to

```
datetime.strptime(Date, "%Y")
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the year as a numeric value instead?

Comment: What is `Date`? We can't really do too much to help if we don't even know what you are running calculations with. I would recommend editing your post into a MCVE as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: This might help [Convert year string into datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how `datetime` interfaces with `pandas` dataframes (perhaps somebody will comment if there is special usage), but in general the `datetime` functions would work like this:

```
import datetime

date_string = "201512"
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y%m")
print(date_object)
```

Getting us:

> 2015-12-01 00:00:00

Now that the hard part of creating a `datetime` object is done we simply

```
print(date_object.year)
```

Which spits out our desired

> 2015

More info about the parsing operators (the "%Y%m" bit of my code) is described [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the module `arrow`

https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
import arrow
date = arrow.now()
#example of text formatting
fdate = date.format('YYYY')

#example of converting text into datetime
date = arrow.get('201905', 'YYYYMM').datetime
```